# What is stored in index leaf nodes when a table has only secondary index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

If a table has a clustered index and a secondary index, the leaf nodes in secondary index contain the attribute value of the clustered index. But what if a table only has non-clustered index? How can a non-clustered index retrieve data without a clustered index?

```sql
create table table_without_primary_key(
    name varchar(30) not null ,
    date datetime not null
);

insert into table_without_primary_key
values ('jack',now());
insert into table_without_primary_key
values ('alice',now());
insert into table_without_primary_key
values ('ribbon',now());

create index time_index
on table_without_primary_key (date);
show index from table_without_primary_key;
```

Result:

```bash
+---------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table                     | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+---------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| table_without_primary_key |          1 | time_index |            1 | date        | A         |           2 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+---------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Besides, I also heard from somewhere that if a table does not have primary key or unique index, it will use row id to create a clustered index.

But I doubt if it is true, since I found no automatic clustered index on row id from the table I described above.

Comment: mysql (or at least innodb) will create a hidden primary key for you (or use an appropriate unique key as the primary key) if you do not have one

Comment: @DaleK - Effectively the "Row ID" is the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (Bill explains what happens if there is not an explicit PK.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All InnoDB tables are stored as a clustered index.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html says:

> If a table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB generates a hidden clustered index named GEN_CLUST_INDEX on a synthetic column that contains row ID values. ...

> The row ID is a 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted.

Comment: Yes, and I found how to show the hidden auto-generated clustered index  (`show index` does not work ) (tested on MySQL 8.0.31): `select t.name as table_name, i.name as index_name
  from information_schema.innodb_tables t
  join information_schema.innodb_indexes i using (table_id)
  where i.name = 'GEN_CLUST_INDEX' and t.name like '%table_without_primary_key%' `

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Bill says, and tested on 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.innodb_index_stats WHERE table_name = 'table_without_primary_key' ;
+---------------+---------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| database_name | table_name                | index_name      | last_update         | stat_name    | stat_value | sample_size | stat_description                  |
+---------------+---------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| try           | table_without_primary_key | GEN_CLUST_INDEX | 2022-12-01 11:39:23 | n_diff_pfx01 |          2 |           1 | DB_ROW_ID                         |
| try           | table_without_primary_key | GEN_CLUST_INDEX | 2022-12-01 11:39:23 | n_leaf_pages |          1 |        NULL | Number of leaf pages in the index |
| try           | table_without_primary_key | GEN_CLUST_INDEX | 2022-12-01 11:39:23 | size         |          1 |        NULL | Number of pages in the index      |
| try           | table_without_primary_key | time_index      | 2022-12-01 11:39:23 | n_diff_pfx01 |          1 |           1 | date                              |
| try           | table_without_primary_key | time_index      | 2022-12-01 11:39:23 | n_diff_pfx02 |          3 |           1 | date,DB_ROW_ID                    |
| try           | table_without_primary_key | time_index      | 2022-12-01 11:39:23 | n_leaf_pages |          1 |        NULL | Number of leaf pages in the index |
| try           | table_without_primary_key | time_index      | 2022-12-01 11:39:23 | size         |          1 |        NULL | Number of pages in the index      |
+---------------+---------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Note that it *does* have a `PRIMARY KEY` called `GEN_CLUST_INDEX`.

A 'row' in a secondary index will have

1. The column(s) of the secondary index, in the order specified.
2. Any other columns that are in the `PRIMARY KEY`.  As already noted, there will always be a PK, but you might see it as a `UNIQUE` or the hidden 6-byte thingie.

There will also be B+Tree overhead stuff, such as links to other nodes, both at the same and other levels.